# how to change pointer in switch statement. Error :invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code in C using emacs, in which I have already received an input, if the input uses any of the following characters I want to substitute them with the rest of the code. But I am receiving an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
void askQuestion(char text[])
{
   for (char * p = text; *p; p++)
   {
      switch (*p)
      {
         case '<':
            *p = "";
            break;
         case '>':
            *p = "";
            break;
         case '#':
            *p = "\n";
            break;
         case '{':
            *p = " \"";
            break;
         case '}':
            *p = "\" ";
            break;
         case '[':
            *p = " \'";
            break;
         case ']':
            *p = "\' ";
            break;
      }

      cout << *p;
   }

}
```

and it's giving me the error

> "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

How can I modify this code to change the pointers? I just want to be able to print out the `*p` with the substituted values. How do I do this? or what would you recommend that I do differently to make this work? or in other words how else could I write this program to modify the input.

Comment: You are assigning a `char` and a `const char*` which is why the compiler is complaining about. Simply change all the `"` to `'` and `""` to `' '`

Comment: @billz I want it to be blank. Im still a newbie at this. :D

Comment: `"` delimits a srting (`char *`), `'` delimits a single char. All assignments within your `switch` statement assign read-only (`const` storage class) strings (`char *`) to a `char`

Comment: @DylanLittle I have removed the `C++` tag from your question, based upon your first sentence in the question body. If it is not correct, feel free to revert. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer considers

> *I have this code in `C`*

`p` is a `char *`  here.

As you're taking one `char` at a time (`switch` case), you need to use a `char` value to populate `*p`, not a *string*, like

```
*p = '\n';
```

and so on.

Remember, a `""` denotes a *string literal* (of type `char *`, in general), whereas a `''` denotes a `char` literal (don't be surprised, it's of type `int`).

That said, in a C code, you can't use `cout`, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: there is a difference at the type of `' '` between C and C++ (question is tagged as both). It is an `int` in C, but a `char` in C++.

Comment: @mch ok, you got it....it's confusing now.... I'll add a line about it. I took the question as `C` only.

Comment: I would tag the question only as C++, OP must use a C++ compiler. It also has nothing to do with emacs.